# Get referenced object multipla layers django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working with Django, I have trouble fetching objects that are chained referenced.
Here we are my Models

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class Element(models.Model):
    environment = models.ForeignKey(Environment, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='GroupPre')

class AlarmActive(models.Model):
    element = models.ForeignKey(Element, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='AlarmActivePre')
```

My task is straightforward, I have to fetch all environments that have an AlarmActive. How can I achieve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by referencing the relationship in reverse, and use `isnull` to check the existence. Since it is possible that an environment has *multiple* `Element`s and an `Element` has *multiple* `AlarmActive`s, we should probably use `.distinct()` here to avoid retrieving the *same* `Environment` multiple times:

```
Environment.objects.filter(GroupPre__AlarmActivePre__isnull=False).distinct()
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT `environment`.*
INNER JOIN `element` ON `environment`.`id` = `element`.`environment_id`
INNER JOIN `alarmactive` ON `element`.`id` = `alarmactive`.`element_id`
WHERE `alarmactive`.`id` IS NOT NULL
```

Note that typically it is advisable to write `related_name`s in *lowercase* (with underscores). Since this will introduce an attribute, and parameters, that are typically written in lowercase as well.

Comment: Thanks! I had to delete "related_name" first, then it worked properly, Thank you!

Comment: @AlviseSembenico: I edited it to work with the related names. But typically related names are written in lowercase.